# HTML select tag

Tags: php, html

How to specify each option at a select tag?,using which attribute (name,id,....)?
and how to recieve it in the server script to detect which option is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a standard select box, in which value and content are different:

```
<select name="color_id">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
```

Upon form submission, `$_GET['color_id']` or `$_POST['color_id']` (depending on the form method) would be set to `2` if the user had selected Blue.

If the content of the option is the value you want to send, no need to repeat yourself; the option's value is set to the content if no other value is specified.

```
<select name="color_id">
  <option>Red</option>
  <option>Blue</option>
  <option>Green</option>
</select>
```

Upon form submission, `$_GET['color_id']` or `$_POST['color_id']` (depending on the form method) would be set to `Blue` if the user had selected Blue.

Comment: @vog: I caught it before you refreshed ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The index in `$_GET` or `$_POST` will be the `name` of the `select` tag. The contents of the array element will be the `value` of the `option`.

Comment: or if the value isn't specified, the text after each option tag

Comment: -1 for the missing example code ... which should IMHO always be present in an answer to a newbie question

Answer (score 0):

You use this:

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value="val1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

As for the server side, it depends on which technology you are using.

**edit** sorry I didn't see you tagged it as php. $_POST or $_GET will contain the "select1" item, depending on which method you're using in your form tag.